# Setting the value attribute in a dropdown menu Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm fairly new to Symfony2 and am working with the form builder trying to create a dropdown menu from the database. I can populate the dropdown without problem but each options value attribute just gets set to a number when it needs to be set to either the options text or no value attribute but I can't find anything in the documentation about setting the value.

```
$builder->add('institution', 'entity', array(
   enter code here     'class' => 'JacksonFramesStoreBundle:Institution',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
                                ->where('i.type = :type')
                                ->setParameter('type', 'University');
                            },
        'empty_value' => 'Select:',
        'empty_data'  => null,
    ));
```

This outputs:

```
<select id="selectUniversity" name="selectUniversity">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">Australian Catholic University</option>
    <option value="2">Australian National University</option>
    <option value="3">Bond University</option>
</select>
```

*EDIT - this is the relevant section of the twig*

```
<!-- University Panel -->
<div id="uniPanel" style="display:none;">
    <p>{{ form_label(form.institution) }}<br />
        <span class="inputLine">
            {{ form_errors(form.institution) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.institution) }}
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Add code from twig template you use.

Comment: What's the problem? The selected value will be automatically converted to the related entity when the form is submitted.

Comment: @AlessandroDesantis but when working with javascript it will not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, after `if ($form->isValid())`, try using:

```
$value = ($entity->getInstitution()) ? $entity->getInstitution()->getId() : null);
```

I don't really know if I really understood your question